# CruiseControl.NET Silverlight Unit Tests Interact with Desktop Windows Server 2008

Tags: continuous-integration, windows-server-2008, cruisecontrol.net

Currently we have CCService running as a Domain account because the build scripts deploy to a network location. However this causes any unit tests that test the view to fail. Due to not being allowed to interact with desktop.

I can change the CCService to run as local system which works however i loose network connectivity.

I also have tried setting up a /interactive cmd.exe but this has been deprecated in Windows Server 2008.

Any Ideas on this one?
Thanks
Jeremy

Answer (score 0):

What about making a new user account specifically for use with CruiseControl and giving it the read permissions necessary to achieve the goal, without compromising security measures?